# Postfix config to require authentication for outgoing mail etc

Tags: postfix

I am looking for a config, but not been able to achieve.

1. To make postfix require authentication for all outgoing mail. what I see like this:
   `Passed CLEAN {RelayedOutbound}, LOCAL [127.0.0.1]`
2. There are mails which are sent as spam by bots or malicious script like xitpl@mydomain.com.

Now mydomain.com is my domain, but xitpl is no mailbox on my server/domain, yet the mail is queued as valid sender.

my config for postfix is like this:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
permit_mynetworks 
permit_sasl_authenticated 
defer_unauth_destination

smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, 
reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, 
check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf,
check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_policy_greylist.cf

smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re, 

reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, permit_mynetworks, 
permit_sasl_authenticated,
check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf,

check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re
```

Is there anything which I am still missing or done a wrong config.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [`reject_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) which allows you to map between SASL authenticated users and addresses they are permitted to use. Otherwise SASL authenticated users can use any `MAIL FROM` address because of `permit_sasl_authenticated`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. is it also possible that say for example to force the authentication for sending mail no matter from localhost or otherwise. Also there are cases as the server hosts many sites, where some scripts make their way through security hole and send mails as sending from localhost and hence are able to create any alias, which is bieing allowed, in these cases `reject_sender_login_mismatch` won't trigger. so is it possible to configure postfix to look up the local mailboxes and not allow any alias outside that.